# check if Image has an external url

Tags: javascript, php

We have created an image gallery addon for Page builder 
which displays images as gallery like so:

`<img class="sppb-img-responsive" src="'.JUri::base(true).'/'.$value->thumb.'" alt="' . $value->title . '">`

But the problem is that when it uses an external image link 
it returns an error like in this example:

`<img class="sppb-img-responsive" src="/dev/ibwintalldev/https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/38/computer-768608_1280.jpg" alt="test">`

Is there any way to detect this problem so as to fix this?

Or to check if the image has an external link?

Thanks
Lahmar

Comment: Could probably get away with a regular expression`^http[s]:`. You could check like so `$isExternal = (bool)preg_match('#^http[s]:#', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/38/computer-768608_1280.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

Why the `src` tag contains `/dev/ibwintalldev/`, because of which image is not displaying. Remove it and try.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img class="sppb-img-responsive" 
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/38/computer-768608_1280.jpg" 
            alt="test">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They're not hand-editing the HTML, they're using scripts, which is generating the code with `/dev/ibwintalldev/`. This answer is ignoring the cause, and as such is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the unwanted text before `https:` like so in javascript:

```
// returns all images on page
images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")

for (let img of images) {
    // replaces extra text from the src 
    img.src = img.src.replace(/(.+?)(?>http)/, "")
}
```

Regex explanation:

> (.+?)  matches everything (if any) up to what follows this (i.e. `http`) and adds to matching group
>
> (?=`http`)  looks ahead for pattern `http` (but doesn't include in matching group so doesn't get replaced)

The following shows the regex working:

```js
let img = new Image;
img.src="/dev/ibwintalldev/https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/38/computer-768608_1280.jpg";

// we apply the regex
img.src = img.src.replace(/(.+?)(?=http)/, "")

console.log(img.src);
```